# Custom Post Type Archive Title Lowercase

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-post-type-archives, theme-thesis

Is there any reason that my custom post type archive title is all lower-case even though 'name' is defined as sentence-case?

Here is the post type function I'm using:

```
function resources_post_type() {
$labels = array(
    'name'               => _x( 'Resources, Help & Support', 'post type general name' ),
    'singular_name'      => _x( 'Resource', 'post type singular name' ),
    'add_new'            => _x( 'Add New', 'resources' ),
    'add_new_item'       => __( 'Add New Resource' ),
    'edit_item'          => __( 'Edit Resource' ),
    'new_item'           => __( 'New Resource' ),
    'all_items'          => __( 'All Resources' ),
    'view_item'          => __( 'View Resource' ),
    'search_items'       => __( 'Search Resources' ),
    'not_found'          => __( 'No resources found' ),
    'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No resources found in the Trash' ), 
    'parent_item_colon'  => '',
    'menu_name'          => 'Resources'
);
$args = array(
    'labels'        => $labels,
    'description'   => 'Holds our resources and resource specific data',
    'public' => true,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'show_in_menu' => true,
    'query_var' => true,
    'menu_position' => 5,
    'has_archive'   => true,
    'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'resources' ),
    'supports' => array(
        'title',
        'editor',
        'author',
        'thumbnail',
        'excerpt'
    )
);
register_post_type( 'resources', $args );   
add_action('admin_init', 'flush_rewrite_rules');
```

}
add_action( 'init', 'resources_post_type', 0 );

I'm using Thesis 2.0

Comment: You are going to need to post some code. This is way too vague.

Comment: Check for your CSS: `text-transform:lowercase;`
In Chrome press F12. In Firefox, use Firebug.

Comment: Sorry @Jake, I've updated my question.

Comment: @trancuong That was my initial thought too but it's definitely not that.

Comment: In the template file, is it possible that anything is forcing lowercase in the PHP? Like "strtolower"?

Comment: @Jake Not that I can see, weirder still is that after changing the name value the title that is being printed is still "resources". I'll update the code accordingly.

Comment: This question is probably impossible to answer without seeing the rendered output.

Comment: @ChipBennett <h1 class="archive_title">resources</h1>

Comment: How do you display the title in the template? Then look into that function and `var_dump( $GLOBALS['wp_filter']['THAT_FILTER'] );` that filter that is inside to see the attached callbacks.

Comment: Nathan, that's the browser source, not the rendered output. Can you provide a live link?

Comment: @ChipBennett http://wearesmile.co.uk/resources/

Comment: @ChipBennett That link isn't gonna be very useful for you now, as I'm using the code in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not the perfect solution, but it will do considering the amount I've spent on it so far. I couldn't find the offending code, but I believe that this is something to do with the Thesis Core.

So instead, I wrote a filter to change the copy based on the post type:

```
function resource_archive_title() {
if (is_post_type_archive('resources')) { ?>
<h1>Resources, Help & Support</h1>
<?php }
}

add_filter('thesis_archive_title', 'resource_archive_title');
```

I'll just add a few elseif statements for other post types.

Answer (score 0):

This is the best way to accomplish this without having to make functions for each type. You just pass the title to the function and you can easily manipulate with the ucfirst() function. Just stick this in custom.php

```
add_filter('thesis_archive_title', 'captialize_archive_title');
function captialize_archive_title($title) {
    return ucfirst($title);
}
```